# How can I fix ANTLR plugin problem in JetBrains IDE?

Tags: plugins, antlr4, jetbrains-ide

I'm getting the following message after generating an ANTLR Recognizer using the ANTLR plugin for JetBrains/Idea.

In the parse tree pane is the following:

> Issues with parser and/or lexer grammar(s) prevent preview; see ANTLR Tool Output pane.

The output pane show now errors messages of problems. It just shows:

> 2023-12-14 22:01:41: `antlr4 -o /Users/mburbidg/Development/gql/grammar/gen -listener -visitor -lib /Users/mburbidg/Development/gql/grammar /Users/mburbidg/Development/gql/grammar/GQLParser.g4 /Users/mburbidg/Development/gql/grammar/GQLLexer.g4`

I find the generated command interesting however because, it generates by default in the gen folder, yet `-lib` is pointing at the top level folder. So I wonder if the tokens file is missing.

I have another parser and lexer project that works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume the most obvious things, like restarting IntelliJ and updating the plugin are already performed. Are you sure the GQLLexer and GQLParser are okay? No errors in them? Generating classes manually, from the command line, works for the grammar files?

Comment: Yes I tried all those things. No errors generating from the command line and the grammar works in http://lab.antlr.org/.

Comment: Hmm, lab.antlr sometimes behaves differently. Can you share the grammar files so that I can (try to) reproduce this?

Comment: I don't want to post them here. I sent them to the email address associated with your github account. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Sorry, if you”re not willing to post them here, so that everyone can have a look, I cannot help. I like helping people on SO so that others might benefit from it.

Comment: I have permission to post the grammar. It is in the following github repo.

https://github.com/mburbidg/gqlgrammar

I have still not been able to find a solution to this. Can you help now @BartKiers?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your grammar: it must be a bug with the plugin. I think the fact that the grammar is split into 2 files in combination with it being rather large is causing problems. You could create an issue [here](https://github.com/antlr/intellij-plugin-v4/issues).

If you make it a [combined grammar](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/dev/doc/grammars.md#grammar-structure)<sup>1</sup>, the plugin *does* work.

<sup>1</sup> name the file `GQL.g4` and copy all lexer- and parser rules into this file, like this: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/bkiers/18231f04322bf2e2f8c9a44ab45cd909/raw/5a3056421c05b799209e18ba61a39aa3805dbb49/GQL.g4

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking a look at this. I used to have them in a single file. I guess it was working then. I made a bunch of changes at the same time that I split them out into two files. So it didn't occur to me that it could be moving to two files that caused the problem. Thanks again!